# Delete button doesn't appear in UITableViewCell

Tags: ios, uitableview

I have got an issue with getting Delete button on Edit one clicks. The problem is being that it doesn't appear at all. My code is below and it works for swiping across a cell... Thank you in advance for the help!

```
#import "ViewController.h"

@interface ViewController ()

@property (strong) NSArray *lessons;

@end

static NSString *identifier = @"Cell";

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    self.lessons = @[
                     @"Computer Science",
                     @"Math",
                     @"Chemistry"
                     ];

    self.tableView = [[UITableView alloc] initWithFrame:self.view.frame style:UITableViewStylePlain];
    self.tableView.dataSource = self;
    self.tableView.delegate = self;
    [self.view addSubview:self.tableView];

    self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = self.editButtonItem;

    [self.tableView registerClass:UITableViewCell.class forCellReuseIdentifier:identifier];
}

#pragma mark - Table view data source

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    return self.lessons.count;
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:identifier];

    cell.textLabel.text = self.lessons[indexPath.row];
    cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator;

    return cell;
}

- (BOOL)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView canEditRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    return YES;
}

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

}

#pragma mark - Table view delegate

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    [tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES];
}

- (UITableViewCellEditingStyle)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView editingStyleForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    return UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete;
}

@end
```

Once I pressed Edit button.
[image]

This appears when I swiped across the cell. 
[image]

Comment: How do you create the edit button?

Comment: Thank you for the comment, I've already solved that issue!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If anyone has the same issue, then you are probably using a `UITableView` in a `UIViewController`, so it doesn't manage editions for you. When you click Edit button, you must implement TableView's editing mode AND View's editing mode manually. How have I solved that issue.

```
#pragma mark - Edit button listener 

- (void)editButtonPressed {
    if(self.editing) {
        [self setEditing:NO animated:YES];
        [self.tableView setEditing:NO animated:YES];
    } else {
        [self setEditing:YES animated:YES];
        [self.tableView setEditing:YES animated:YES];
    }
}
```

Thank you guys for commenting!

Answer (score 1):

hear above coding see that its really useful for that.

```
  - (HelloController *) init
    {
        if (!(self = [super init])) return self;

        self.title = @"Table Edits";

        // Initialize the table titles, so they can be edited over time
        tableTitles = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
        ithTitle = NCELLS;
        for (int i = 1; i <= NCELLS; i++)
            [tableTitles addObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Table Cell #%d", i]];

        return self;
    }

    #pragma mark UITableViewDataSource Methods

    - (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
    {
        return 1;
    }

    - (NSInteger)tableView :(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
    {
        return [tableTitles count];
    }

    - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
    {
        UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"any-cell"];
        if (cell == nil) {
            cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero reuseIdentifier:@"any-cell"] autorelease];
        }

        cell.text = [tableTitles objectAtIndex:[indexPath row]];
        // cell.editingStyle = UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete; // now read-only and no longer needed
        return cell;
    }

    - (void) add
    {
        [tableTitles addObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Table Cell #%d", ++ithTitle]];
        [self.tableView reloadData];
    }

    #pragma mark UITableViewDelegateMethods
    - (void) deselect
    {
        [self.tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:[self.tableView indexPathForSelectedRow] animated:YES];
    }

    // Respond to user selection
    - (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)newIndexPath
    {
        printf("User selected row %d\n", [newIndexPath row] + 1);
        [self performSelector:@selector(deselect) withObject:nil afterDelay:0.5f];
    }

    -(void)leaveEditMode
    {
        // Add the edit button
        self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = [[[UIBarButtonItem alloc]
                                                   initWithTitle:@"Edit"
                                                   style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain
                                                   target:self
                                                   action:@selector(enterEditMode)] autorelease];
        [self.tableView endUpdates];
        [self.tableView setEditing:NO animated:YES];
    }

    - (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle
    forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
    {
        printf("About to delete item %d\n", [indexPath row]);
        [tableTitles removeObjectAtIndex:[indexPath row]];
        [tableView reloadData];
    }

    -(void)enterEditMode
    {
        // Add the edit button
        self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = [[[UIBarButtonItem alloc]
                                                   initWithTitle:@"Done"
                                                   style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain
                                                   target:self
                                                   action:@selector(leaveEditMode)] autorelease];
        [self.tableView setEditing:YES animated:YES];
    //  [self.tableView beginUpdates];
    }

    - (void)loadView
    {
        [super loadView];

        // Add an add button
        self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = [[[UIBarButtonItem alloc]
                                                  initWithTitle:@"New"
                                                  style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain
                                                  target:self
                                                  action:@selector(add)] autorelease];

        // Add the edit button
        self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = [[[UIBarButtonItem alloc]
                                                   initWithTitle:@"Edit" 
                                                   style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain 
                                                   target:self 
                                                   action:@selector(enterEditMode)] autorelease];
    }
```